# How to disable alignment of individual lines in an align environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I often write definitions like

```
\begin{align*}
   f &: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}
 \\ f(0) &: 0
 \\ f(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{x}
\end{align*}
```

[image: rendered version of the badly aligned version]

<sup>(Yeah, I know this could also be written with a `cases` environment, but I'm not asking about that.)</sup>

Needless to say, the alignment is a bit of a mess here. I do want the `=` signs to be aligned, but it doesn't really make sense for the colon. In principle, that should just be centered by itself, and the equations below centered as well as a block, like would happen with two separate environments

[image: separate environments]

but that has its own disadvantages, including the undesired vertical space.

It's no good to just omit the alignment character

```
\begin{align*}
   f &: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}
 \\ f(0) &: 0
 \\ f(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{x}
\end{align*}
```

as that just smashes the first line entirely in the left alignment column

[image: smashleft]

Nesting environments doesn't do the trick either

```
\begin{align*}
   f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}
 \\
\begin{aligned}
    f(0) &= 0
 \\ f(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

– this seems to result in the same as the first version, for some reason.

What's the proper way?

---

Related questions:

- [Alignment like in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250235/alignment-like-in-align-environment) asks also about a different-aligned first line, but not centered. The solution involves a manual alignment point. That's really awkward and should not be necessary if the first line should just be individually centered.
- [How to align only some equations in an align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137041/how-to-align-only-some-equations-in-an-align-environment) is more about adding additional padding to align specific lines within an already aligned environment

Comment: FTR, I actually meant to write `f(0) = 1`, but only noticed the discontinuity at zero in the finished question. Not that it matters for what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest an `aligned` environment (for rows 2 and 3) inside a `gather*` environment:

[image]

Do also note that I've inserted a typographic strut (via a `\vphantom` directive) in row 2 in order to separate it a bit more from rows 1 and 3. Furthermore, I would use `\colon` rather than `:` in row 1.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
   f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\
   \begin{aligned}
     f(0) &= 1 \vphantom{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \\
     f(x) &= \frac{\sin x}{x}
   \end{aligned} 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```